# Parse a lambda expression into components

Tags: c#, reflection, lambda, expression

I am writing a method which accepts a lambda expression as a parameter and parses its properties from left to right.  The following criteria should be met:

1. The expression must only use simple property or fields -- no method calls or LINQ queries or anything more complex.  (e.g. p => p.HomeAddress.City)  The method can throw an exception if the expression does not meet these criteria.
2. The method should return a list of info about each property or field: name and type.

How can this be accomplished?

```
    private List<SomeClass> ParseExpression<T1,T2>(Expression<Func<T1, T2>> func)
    {
        // ??
    }
```

Comment: Get a copy of LINQPad and you can `Dump` the expression values for different expressions to see what you need to do to parse them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This:

```
private static IReadOnlyList<Tuple<string, Type>> ParseExpression<T1, T2>(Expression<Func<T1, T2>> func)
{
    var par = func.Parameters[0];

    var lst = new List<Tuple<string, Type>>();

    Expression exp = func.Body;

    while (exp != par)
    {
        if (exp.NodeType != ExpressionType.MemberAccess)
        {
            throw new Exception(exp.ToString());
        }

        MemberExpression me = (MemberExpression)exp;

        MemberInfo mi = me.Member;

        if (mi.MemberType == MemberTypes.Field)
        {
            FieldInfo fi = (FieldInfo)mi;
            lst.Add(Tuple.Create(fi.Name, fi.FieldType));
        }
        else if (mi.MemberType == MemberTypes.Property)
        {
            PropertyInfo pi = (PropertyInfo)mi;
            lst.Add(Tuple.Create(pi.Name, pi.PropertyType));
        }
        else
        {
            throw new Exception(exp.ToString());
        }

        exp = me.Expression;
    }

    lst.Reverse();

    return lst;
}
```

Example:

```
class Cl1
{
    public Cl2 Cl2; 
}

class Cl2
{
    public string Str { get; set; }
}
```

and then:

```
var result = ParseExpression<Cl1, string>(x => x.Cl2.Str);

foreach (var el in result)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{el.Item1}: {el.Item2}");
}
```

Comment: This approach looks promising.  I will look at it later before accepting this answer.  Thank you.